# angular ngx-infinite-scroll reset currentScrollPosition

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

I am new in development and trying to use angular with ngx-infinite-scroll.
I would like to use this in one component but with different routes.
For example: /all -> all data or /fruits-> only just filtered data.

When I reach the first trigger point and the data is loading then I switch to an another route and getting scroll down.

The problem is when I switched to another route there no more trigger from scrolling.
No more onScrollDown() function run.

This problem appear only just I switch route immediately the first trigger.(first run onScrollDown())
If I reach the second or more trigger point then everything works perfectly.

Is There any opportunity to trigger the onScrollDown() function if I switch route after the first trigger or set the currentScrollPostion to 0?

Thank You!

I made a simple demo to represent my issue.
In the console will appear when the onScrollDown() function will be triggered.
[Angular Infinite Scroll Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aypkco)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to reset the infinite-scroll.
When the route is changing, I run a method with these setup.

[Reset the ngx-infinite-scroll from angular](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll/issues/327)